# ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException Using Redis Cluster and Twemproxy

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, twemproxy

I have a 3 master / 3 slave Redis cluster running on a single Ubuntu 14_04 machine. I followed the guide published [here](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) when creating the cluster.  I also have Nutcracker running on the same machine. Everything starts up and appears to be functioning correctly in the cluster. I wrote a small c# app using the ServiceStack.Redis v3 API and it's throwing an exception whenever I attempt to write to the Redis Cluster.  Here's the response:

An unhandled exception of type 'ServiceStack.Redis.RedisResponseException' occurred in ServiceStack.Redis.dll

Additional information: MOVED 5836 192.168.120.147:7001, sPort: 54812, LastCommand: SET foo_1 "bar_1"

Here's the code i'm using:

ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient redisClient = 
new ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient("192.168.120.147");

redisClient.Set("foo_1", "bar_1");

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Nutcracker Config:
redis_cluster:
  auto_eject_hosts: true
  distribution: ketama
  hash: fnv1a_64
  listen: 0.0.0.0:6379
  preconnect: true
  redis: true
  server_retry_timeout: 30000
  server_failure_limit: 3
  timeout: 400
  servers:
   - 192.168.120.147:7000:1 M1
   - 192.168.120.147:7001:1 M2
   - 192.168.120.147:7002:1 M3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, nutcracker isn't compatible (yet?) with the Redis Cluster Specification and can only be used with Redis' traditional unclustered mode. That means you can use one (the open source Redis Cluster), the other (the open source nutcracker proxy), neither but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks,  I turned clustering off and it appears to be working now.  I'll look into handling the master/slave replication another way.

Comment: Master/slave replication doesn't require the use of any clustering solution - it is a basic Redis capability that's entirely transparent to your client library in all but select few use cases.